# extract data from a nested array json using pl/sql

Tags: json, plsql

I am trying to extract analyzed info for related product. I am wondering how can I get analyzed data in order.
As you see I haven't any related data to match the analysis to products except paternal node.

```
{
    "Data": {
        "WayBillNumber": "99081930",
        "ContractCode": "199128",
        "OrderNumber": "52116069004",
        "TransferTime": "14:05",
        "LocationWagon": "6485317",
        "BusinessQuality": "St 372",
        "DriverNationalCode": "1757830294",
        "DriverMobile": "09160662694",
        "TotalBascolicWeight": 30500.0,
        "TotalQuantity": 3.0,
        "ProductionList": [
            {
                "ProductionCode": "499251501010",
                "Length": 4190.0,
                "Width": 1250.0,
                "Thickness": 245.0,
                "Quantity": 1.0,
                "BascolicWeight": 10102.0,
                "TheoryWeight": 0.0,
                "HeatNumber": "49925150",
                "AnalyzeModelItems": [
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "C",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.16"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "SI",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.25"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ProductionCode": "399242402080",
                "Length": 4230.0,
                "Width": 1250.0,
                "Thickness": 245.0,
                "Quantity": 1.0,
                "BascolicWeight": 10198.0,
                "TheoryWeight": 0.0,
                "HeatNumber": "39924240",
                "AnalyzeModelItems": [
                    
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "TI",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.001"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "CO",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.006"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "W",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.006"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "PB",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.002"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "SN",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.005"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ProductionCode": "399242402070",
                "Length": 4230.0,
                "Width": 1250.0,
                "Thickness": 245.0,
                "Quantity": 1.0,
                "BascolicWeight": 10200.0,
                "TheoryWeight": 0.0,
                "HeatNumber": "39924240",
                "AnalyzeModelItems": [
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "C",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.15"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "SI",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.26"
                    },
                    {
                        "AnalyseCode": "MN",
                        "AnalyseValue": "0.66"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Messages": [
        "اطلاعات بارنامه"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the oracle database version is 12.2 or higher you can save the json data in a
table with column datatype as clob and add the check json constraint.
By doing so you can access the json key values in dot notation.

Eg usage:

```
SELECT ct.clob_column."Data".ProductionList[*]."ProductionCode" 
    FROM HR.CLOB_TABLE ct ;
```

Addition info refer [Oracle Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-store-query-and-create-json-documents-in-oracle-database)

Comment: No actually it's 11g

Comment: No actually it's 11g